# Could you help resolve this logic issue?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/jason5149/w4eL58gw/2/)`DEMO`

You can see code above link.

Actually, I want to according the button group's input to control all of input form which name is the same with button group name.

For example, I put value into input form on the 'First' Button right side,

and the same time, all of the input form which name 'First' should be change

with just button group input one.

Sorry for my poor English skill, hope you can understand it!!

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
// list group
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="price">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


// button group
  <div>
    <ul class="list-btn">
      <li ng-repeat="btn in btns">
        <button>{{btn}}</button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="price_all">    
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>


angular.module('app', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'First'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Second'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Third'},
    {id: 4, name: 'First'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Second'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Third'},
    {id: 7, name: 'First'},
    {id: 8, name: 'Second'},
    {id: 9, name: 'Third'},
  ]

  $scope.btns = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];

}])
```

Comment: Could you please put the code in the post? jsFiddle is awesome, but it's better [to put you code in the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: do you need to click the button to reflect the change or instantly?

Comment: use a service to store the data and you will have all automagically syncronized

Comment: you guys can click example link!

Comment: @KarthikMR button just to submit data to backend, you can ignore it

Comment: No, do not link to external sites. This site is made for posting the code.

Comment: @JanHenke ok, let me put code here

Comment: @JanHenke It's done, you can see code here now

Comment: check the link https://jsfiddle.net/fcoLmd2n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ng-model is repeated insisde li tag, the two-way binding will work only inside that li tag, not outside of it. So, you need to use onkeyup event.

Working solution in the fiddlder - https://jsfiddle.net/fcoLmd2n/

Do these changes in html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <input type="text" class="{{item.name}}" ng-model="price">
  </li>

<li ng-repeat="btn in btns">
    <button>{{btn}}</button>
    <input type="text" btnType="{{btn}}" ng-model="price_all" onkeyup="Update(this);">
</li>
```

Changes in Js file:

```
function Update(obj)
{
    var className = obj.getAttribute('btnType');
    var txtBoxElements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var i=0;i<txtBoxElements.length;i++)
    {
        txtBoxElements[i].value= obj.value
    }
}
```

Use Jquery for optimization

Comment: Yeah, I also thought that I should use jquery to control it. Thank you a million!!

Comment: I just gave you the logic. You can tune according to your need and also use jquery. Happy coding!